# Nginx, render a file with dynamic name

Tags: nginx

I have a cachebreaker that produces css filenames as this one: `/css/vendor.min.333311133.css`.

I want nginx to answer request with a previous version with the latest.

Note that I will only have one version of that file in the directory... so I'm thinking of a rule like the following, but it's not working:

```
  location ~* /css\/vendor\.min\.(.*)\.css {
        try_files $uri ~* /css\/vendor\.(.*)\.css =404;
    }
```

Does anybody knows if nginx support dynamic names in try_files? Or should I use another directive? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your build process is able to do this, just put the file there without the cachebreaker part and do this:

```
location ~* /css\/vendor\.min\.(.*)\.css {
  try_files /css/vendor.min.css =404;
}
```

In theory you can use a regex capture inside the location, but since the old version number would be in there, it would not help.